# Globally-used class

Tags: ios, class

I have Alert calls in many classes and I would like to have one Alert class that handles all the uses, i.e. wherever an Alert is needed, that Alert class is called. All the Alert code is in one place.

Right now I have Alert code repeated in every class where it appears. I want one set of Alert code.

How do I do it?

Comment: I have written a long answer. I hope it will help you. By the way, are you coding in Objective C or Swift ?

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try and do this? Please don't just ask people to do the work for you. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work, to demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from giving obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class for your alert.

```
class MyCustomAlertView{

static let sharedUtils = MyCustomAlertView()

class func showAlertOnVC(targetVC: UIViewController, title: String, message: String)
{
    // write custom code here
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let okButton = UIAlertAction(
        title:"OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler:
        {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!)  in
    })
    alert.addAction(okButton)
    targetVC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

Wherever in project you need to call alert, call as below:

```
MyCustomAlertView.showAlertOnVC(targetVC: self, title: "MyTitle", message:  "test message") // whatever title and message you want
```

Answer (score 0):

For Alerts you can use third party libraries such as :

- [DQAlertView](https://github.com/dinhquan/DQAlertView) for Objective C
- [SwiftAlertView](https://github.com/dinhquan/SwiftAlertView) for Swift

Check them out, it is very useful.

Moreover, if you want to do it yourself, you can create a custom class.

For example :

```
public class AlertUtils {

     // Build classic Alert with OK Button
    class func buildAlertInfo(withTitle title: String?, andMessage message: String?, withHandler handler: (UIAlertAction -> Void)?) -> UIAlertController {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: handler))
        return alertController
    }

    // Build custom Alert with an OK Button and a redirection Button
    class func buildAlertInfoWithFavButton(withTitle title: String?, andMessage message: String?, withHandler handler: [((UIAlertAction) -> Void)]?) -> UIAlertController {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: handler!.first))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Favoris", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: handler!.last))

        return alertController
    }
}
```

With this class you can build and customize your Alerts like you want. You want an Alert with an "OK" button and a "Settings" buttons.
You can create as many customized methods in order to build specifics Alerts.

Here is how you use it :

```
let alert = AlertUtils.buildAlertInfo(withTitle: NSLocalizedString("alert_info_title", comment: ""),
                                                         andMessage: NSLocalizedString("alert_message", comment: ""), withHandler: nil)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**NB :** Keep in mind that it is a best practice to regroup all your strings in the NSLocalizedString.

An other example with handlers :

```
let alert = AlertUtils.buildAlertInfoWithFavButton(
                withTitle: "Alert Info"
                andMessage: "Whatever you want",
                withHandler: [okHandler, favoriteHandler]
            )
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And you can do custom actions for your Alert Buttons in Handlers

```
//Ok handler
    func okHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    //Favorite handler to redirect to the Favorite View Controller
    func favoriteHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FavoritesViewController(), animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class method for your class and write common alertview code, so that you don't require any instances of it. 
Then just import this generic class and then you could call class method in any view controller something like:

[InternetAlert showAlert];